# How to call a userform's subroutine within a a separate module's subroutine with VBA

Tags: vba, instantiation

I am wondering how I can call a public subroutine that resides within a userform of two option buttons. Specifically if that user selections optionbutton1 from that userform is selected, then run some code from a sub routine within a module.

In the UserForm code:

```
    Public Sub OptionButton1_Click()
        Optionbutton1 = True
        Optionbutton2 = False
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub OptionButton2_Click()
        Optionbutton1 = False
        Optionbutton2 = True
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub TextBox1_Change()
    
    End Sub
```

In Module:

```
   Global Optionbutton1 As Integer
   Global Optionbutton2 As Integer 
-------------------------------------------------------------  
   Sub ProjectSetup(Optionbutton1. Optionbutton2)
       
       Call UserForm1.OptionButton1_Click
       Call UserForm1.OptionButton2_Click
       
       If OptionButton1 = True then
           [do some action]
   
       If OptionButton2 = True then
           [do some action]
```

I think my issue is based on how I am trying to call in the subroutines "OptionButton1_Click" and "OptionButton2_Click" from UserForm1. When I run the code above I get a compiling error that states the function or sub not defined.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you showing the form? What specific problem are you having? - do you get an error message?  What is the message and on which line of code?

Comment: I am using UserForm1.show to show the form. My specific problem is that i am not able to call or instantiate the userform and its subroutines pertaining to the optionbuttons

Comment: From your description it seems like you want to call the module code from the form code, but the posted VBA seems like the opposite?  Note when you `Show` a form, all code in `ProjectSetup` beyond that point is suspended until the userform is closed (hidden or unloaded)

Comment: I want to call the userform code regarding OptionButton1 and OptionButton2 within the module. Apologies for the poor description

Comment: I can't follow why you'd need to do it that way?  If something needs to happen when the form loads, typically you have code in the form to make sure that happens.

Comment: I would rather have the code stay within the modules rather than transfer it to the userform. All i need to do is insatiate the userform and its functions within my module, im sure there is methods to do so

Comment: What about this though? `If OptionButton1_Click = True then`   You're calling a sub, not a Function, so it's not going to return true/false.  What is happening inside of `OptionButton1_Click` and `OptionButton2_Click` ?

Comment: I see. I modified the question/code to contain two variables that are true/false. The variables "Optionbutton1" and "Optionbutton2" should be callable within my modules so i can use the two variables within a conditional statement in this module.

Comment: Did you add those variables as Public Globals in your form module?

Comment: Yes i did add these variables as public globals but have compile errors. Any suggestions? Ive updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* the right way to do whatever it is you're doing, but this would work.

In `UserForm1`:

```vb
Public Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    gOpt1 = True  'setting the public globals declared in the calling module
    gOpt2 = False
End Sub

Public Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    gOpt1 = False
    gOpt2 = True
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public gOpt1 As Boolean
Public gOpt2 As Boolean

Sub Tester()

    Dim frm As UserForm1
    
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    
    gOpt1 = False 'reset globals
    gOpt2 = False
    
    frm.Show vbModeless 'Must be modeless, or the code stops here
                        '  until the form is closed
    
    Debug.Print gOpt1, gOpt2  '> False, False
    frm.OptionButton1_Click
    Debug.Print gOpt1, gOpt2  '> True, False
    frm.OptionButton2_Click
    Debug.Print gOpt1, gOpt2  '> False, True
    
    Unload frm

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution, works in my application.